# Where should public key go?

Tags: server

I'm working locally on windows and am trying to set up a new ubuntu 16.04 vps to use a public key. I'm planning to use a non-root user to do my deployment. The root path of the user is /home/my_name. Should the public key go in a directory under the root or under the /home/my_name directory?

Comment: You don't specify what you will use the public key for, but I'm quite sure you don't want it in the `/root` directory (much less in `/ `). The reason is that your local user `my_name` needs to retrieve it, and ordinary users have no business looking around in those directories. If you mean `ssh` keys, there are specific places for that kind of files (usually `/home/my_name_/.ssh`).

Comment: Thanks Jos, yes its an ssh key. I'm planning to deploy mainly with git and fabric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are trying to SSH from the Windows machine into the VPS.  You would copy the public key into the home directory of the user you plan on using for your deployment, which you say is "my_name".  Paste the public key from your Windows SSH client into the below directory:

```
/home/my_name/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Make sure you paste it exactly how it looks.  Watch for wordwrapping.  Make sure you grab the "pub" file.

Hmm, you mention deploying with 'git'.  Sounds like you might also need to generate a key, or copy your existing key-pair into your '.ssh' directory.  This will allow you to pull/push your git code.

If you want to generate a new keypair for the VPS, run `ssh-keygen`, and then grab the `pub` file from the `.ssh` directory and paste it into your git provider (github?).